# Merging data giving numeric error when running code

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to merge datasets together using RStudio and I am receiving. Is there anywhay to get the two to be read properly? The data source is from
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/diabetes/

> merged.data <- merge(data-01, data-02)
>   Error in data - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

merged.data <- merge(data-01, data-02)
merged.data

Comment: The data frames don't have syntactically valid names (`-` is not a valid character for an object name) so you'll need to wrap them in backticks `merge(\`data-01\`, \`data-02\`)`.

Comment: The raw data files do not have any column names. How are you reading in the data files?

Comment: Whenn I try merge(`data-01`, `data-02`), it reads the variables and not the dataset                                                                                                                                                        x
y
1 data-01 data-02

Answer (score 0):

If you read in the data files:

```
df1 <- read.table("data-01")
df2 <- read.table("data-02")
```

You can add rows of one table to the other:

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Is that what you need?

Look closely at the `README` and `Data-Codes` files. There are 70 patients with diabetes. Depending on your needs, you might want an additional variable indicating which patient the data belongs to?

The data frames should have a 4-column format: `Date`, `Time`, `Code`, and `Value`.